# Knockout: manually update an observable via code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to update a value in the knockout model when an event has fired, or more specifically after a button click.  I'm having trouble with the updating part.

I have simplified the model a bit until I get a better grasp on how to use knockout but basically the user will do a lookup/search for a person, and the selected record should updated with the person they choose form the search results.

In the example here I am trying to set the Property Manager on the selected Property after clicking a button on the form.  The click fires my setByCode function which I intended to update the value in the model.  (Eventually the data will come from a json result rather than how it is now)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wm893/1/

It's not updating the selected property for me.

HTML

```
<button data-bind='click: setByCode'>Update Selected Manager</button>
<div data-bind="with: selectedProperty"><h2>Selected: <span data-bind="text: addrSuburb"></span></h2>
</div>
<section>
    <article data-bind="foreach: properties">
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.selectedProperty" >SELECT</button>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: addrLine1" />
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: addrSuburb" />
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: propertyManager" />
        <ul id="rentalAgreements" data-bind="foreach: rentalAgreements">
            <li>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: weeklyRate" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </article>
</section>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

ViewModel

```
var initialData = [{
    addrLine1: ko.observable("1 Small St"),
    addrSuburb: ko.observable("Brisbane"),
    rentalAgreements: [{
        weeklyRate: ko.observable("200")
    }, {
        weeklyRate: ko.observable("210")
    }],
    propertyManager: ko.observable("")
}, {
    addrLine1: ko.observable("23 Another St"),
    addrSuburb: ko.observable("Ipswich"),
    rentalAgreements: [{
        weeklyRate: ko.observable("180")
    }],
    propertyManager: ko.observable("Property Manager 1")
}];

var PortfolioModel = function (properties) {
    var self = this;
    this.properties = ko.observableArray(
    ko.utils.arrayMap(properties,

    function (property) {
        return {
            addrLine1: property.addrLine1,
            addrSuburb: property.addrSuburb,
            rentalAgreements: ko.observableArray(property.rentalAgreements),
            propertyManager: property.propertyManager
        };
    }));

    self.selectedProperty = ko.observable();

    self.setByCode = function () {
        //var data = { "propertyManager": "Property Manager 2" };
        // will come from an ajax response
     self.selectedProperty.propertyManager = "Property Manager 2";
     //alert("update fired");   
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new PortfolioModel(initialData));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't clarified the the steps. To be working your model some changes in **setByCode** function.

```
self.setByCode = function () {
    //var data = { "propertyManager": "Property Manager 2" };
    // will be an ajax response
 self.selectedProperty().propertyManager("Property Manager 2");
 alert("update fired");   
};
```

> As **self.selectedProperty** is observable and **propertyManager** is also observable so you can't assigned and call by dot. We have to use observable **getter** and **setter** functions.
>   For current case 
>    ***self.selectedProperty().propertyManager("Property Manager 2");***

[**Here is working Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wm893/2/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Wm893/4/

The problem was in the self.setByCode callback. I changed

```
self.selectedProperty.propertyManager = "Property Manager 2";
```

to

```
self.selectedProperty().propertyManager("Property Manager 2");
```

Whole function becomes:

```
self.setByCode = function () {
    //var data = { "propertyManager": "Property Manager 2" };
    // will be an ajax response
 self.selectedProperty().propertyManager("Property Manager 2");
 alert("update fired");   
};
```

What I did was add brackets where you were using observables, so after selectedProperty, and in the assignment of propertyManager. Remember that to update the value of an observable, you need to assign using function syntax, instead of direct assignment. The same is the case for getting the value of 'self.selectedProperty'. Without the (), you get the observable. Add the () to get the actual value at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Since selectedProperty and propertyManager are observable properties, you can set the value of the propertyManager in the next way:

```
self.selectedProperty().propertyManager("Property Manager 2");
```

Full example is here http://jsfiddle.net/yaWJ7/2/